# Hibernate one-to-one: AnnotationException Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, one-to-one

I've done my code like it had been done it in examples in google. I tried to make one-to-one relationship. But I get error: AnnotationException Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne

**Question**: what is wrong?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "filesInfo")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class FileInfo {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "file_info_sequence", sequenceName = "sq_file_info")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "file_info_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long fileID;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="fileInfo", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private FileContent fileContent;

    //......
}

@Entity
@Table(name="file_content")
public class FileContent{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property",       value="fileInfo"))
    private long fileID;

    @JsonIgnore
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private FileInfo fileInfo;
    //....
}
```

***Error:***
*java.lang.IllegalStateException*: Failed to load ApplicationContext

*Caused by*: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:src/test/resources/applicationContextTest.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne: FileContent.fileInfo in mappedBy of FileInfo.fileContent

*Caused by:* org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne: FileContent.fileInfo in mappedBy of FileInfo.fileContent

.......

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to add @OneToOne annotation to FileContent.fileInfo field.